# react router duplicated URL params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I know this issue has to do with a fundamental misunderstanding of how React Router works, and more specifically, probably the history object. I have a component called Search, which lets the user search for a particular city. This component appears in multiple places throughout the app, including '/' and '/:cityname'.

From '/', the component works as expected, and correctly pushes the new url param onto the url and the url becomes '/vancouver'. However, from '/vancouver', when I use this same component, the url does not behave as expected. For instance if I enter Istanbul, I am correctly directed to /istanbul, but then as I proceed through the app and click on items, I expect to be directed to '/istanbul/item1'. However, what happens currently is that I end up at '/istanbul/istanbul/item1', which of course is not found, and returns a 404.

Here is the function that gets called when a city is selected (found within Search component)

```
    const onSuggestionSelected = (event, { suggestion }) => {
        props.history.push(`/${suggestion.nickname}`)
    }
```

App.js with routes

```
 <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route exact path="/terms-of-service" component={TermsOfServicePage} />
            <Route exact path="/privacy-policy" component={PrivacyPolicyPage} />
            <Route exact path="/:cityname/personalize" component={FilterPage} />
            <Route exact path="/:cityname/experiences" component={SearchPage}>
              <Redirect to="/:cityname" />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/:cityname" component={SearchPage} />
            <Route exact path="/:cityname/experiences/:experiencename" component={ExperiencePage} />
            <Route exact path="/:cityname/experiences/:experiencename/summary" component={(routeProps) => <SummaryPage {...routeProps} />} />
            <Route exact path="/:cityname/experiences/:experiencename/payment" component={PaymentPage} />
            <Route exact path="/:cityname/experiences/:experiencename/payment-successful" component={PaymentSuccessfulPage} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            <GlobalStyle />
  </Switch>
```

ExploreMore Button

```
                <ButtonWrapper onClick={sendAnalyticsData}>
                    <LetsGoButton to={{
                        pathname: `${props.match.params.cityname}/experiences/${experience.nickname}`,
                        state: props.location.state
                    }}
                    palette="tertiary">
                        Explore more
                    </LetsGoButton>
                </ButtonWrapper>
```

Please let me know if there is anything else that I can provide that would be helpful. I've tried to do research on how history.push works exactly, but I haven't been able to find much. My best guess is that it takes the current location, and adds on the provided url. Even if that's the case, I can't understand why it would be applying istanbul twice.

[image]

Comment: afaik, by now react router does not support relative urls intentionally. So it's rather unexpected behavior. What's the version do you use?

Comment: using react router v4. The thing is, I'm trying to use absolute URLs. as can be seen, the absolute url being requested is `/${suggestion.nickname}/` (which turns out to be /istanbul, /vancouver etc)

Comment: Can you share your main routing code or start point?

Comment: @Garry thank you. updated

Comment: Any reason for using "<Redirect to="/:cityname" />" as you already have defined the route for it.

Comment: no good reason, but taking that out did not solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: Can you share your code for your item button "explore more" ? Something might be wrong with it.

Comment: @Darkilen sure. updated, thank you !

Answer (score 6):

I figured out the problem on this one. One of the commenters suggested that I had been using relative paths rather than absolute. I erroneously thought that he was incorrect, seeing as I seemingly have the full url in there. My mistake was to not start off the url with `/`

before:
 `${props.match.params.cityname}/experiences/${experience.nickname}`

after:
`/${props.match.params.cityname}/experiences/${experience.nickname}`

I hope this helps someone out.

Comment: I was about waste my life but this saved my precious minutes.